# Tengo un error que no puedo identificar PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un problema y es que al hacer un CRUD y añadir los datos pongo todo correctamente y me dice que hay un error y no entiendo lo que esta pasando , Alguna persona me puede decir que le esta pasando que llevo unos dias que no encuentro la solucion y lo tengo que entregar en unos dias y no se como hacerlo si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho

Saludos

```
<?php


//si el formulario ha sido enviado procedo a ingresar contenido en la bbdd
if(isset($_POST['sw']) == 1){

    //conexion a bbdd
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'concesionario');

    //Consulta de insercion. Se reciben los valores de los inputs del formulario enviados por POST
    $query = "INSERT INTO product (id,name, price, description, provider) VALUES ('".$_POST['in_id']."','".$_POST['in_name']."', '".$_POST['in_price']."', '".$_POST['in_description']."', '".$_POST['in_provider']."' )";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $query)){ // si la consulta se ejecuto con exito muestro mensaje y redirecciono a index.php
        echo "La informacion se guardo con exito";
        header('Location: indice.php');
    }else{ //si hubo error muestro mensaje de error
        echo "Ocurrio un error al intentar guardar";
    }

    //cierro conexion a bbdd
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRUD basico con PHP y MySQL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h3>Nuevo usuario</h3>
        <form action="create.php" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='in_id' size='10'</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='in_name' size='10'</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='in_price' size='10'</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='in_description' size='10'</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='in_provider' size='10'</td>
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" /><br /><br />
            <a class="btn" href="indice.php"><< Volver</a>
            <input type="hidden" name="created" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="sw" value="1" />
        </tr>
        </form>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y el error que te muestra ???

Comment: Me sale cuando lo hago : Ocurrio un error al intentar guardar

Comment: @JosepGiner la forma en la que evalúas posibles errores no es funcional (*al menos no para depurar*), revisa la [doc. oficial de PHP y usa `mysqli_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples) para saber que ocurre realmente

Comment: Entonces es un problema de la query. Realiza un `echo $query` justo después de esta misma.  Y luego del `mysqli_query`, has un echo mysqli_error($link)

Comment: me sale este error : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`concesionario`.`product`, CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`provider`) REFERENCES `provider` (`name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: y el provider esta dado de alta en la tabla a la cual se refiere el constrain?

Comment: tiene pinta que tienes una constraint entre dos tablas. Y por lo tanto te falta crear un registro en `provider` antes de poder crearla en esta tabla.